# How to mock inner method in mocking class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I want to test my Google API client but I don't know how to mock inner methods that are called when the main method runs. I'm also not sure for now if I mock the restTemplate method properly but I'd like to focus on those inner methods.

```
public List<GoogleItemDto> getRatings() {
    URI url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves/2/volumes")
            .build().encode().toUri();
    try {
        Credential credentials = getCredentials();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBearerAuth(credentials.getAccessToken());
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("body", headers);

        ResponseEntity<GoogleBooksRatingDto> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, GoogleBooksRatingDto.class);

        return Optional.ofNullable(Objects.requireNonNull(response.getBody()).getItems())
                .map(Arrays::asList)
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> Objects.nonNull(p.getGoogleVolumeInfoDtos()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (RestClientException | GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}

public Credential getCredentials() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setClientSecrets(clientConfig.getClientId(), clientConfig.getClientSecret())
            .build();
    credential.setAccessToken(getNewToken());
    credential.setRefreshToken(clientConfig.getRefreshToken());
    return credential;
}

public String getNewToken() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
    scopes.add(clientConfig.getScope());
    TokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
            clientConfig.getRefreshToken(), clientConfig.getClientId(), clientConfig.getClientSecret()).setScopes(scopes).setGrantType("refresh_token").execute();
    return tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
}
```

The methods getCredentials and getNewToken were basically private but I change to public just to see if I can figure out some way to handle my problem.

Here is test method.

```
    @Test
void testGetRatings() {
    // Given
    when(clientConfig.getRefreshToken()).thenReturn("test");
    when(clientConfig.getClientId()).thenReturn("test");
    when(clientConfig.getClientSecret()).thenReturn("test");
    when(clientConfig.getScope()).thenReturn("test");

    URI url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves/2/volumes")
            .build().encode().toUri();

    GoogleImageLinksDto googleImageLinksDto = new GoogleImageLinksDto();

    GoogleVolumeInfoDto volumeInfoDto = new GoogleVolumeInfoDto();
    volumeInfoDto.setGoogleImageLinksDto(googleImageLinksDto);

    GoogleItemDto item = new GoogleItemDto();
    item.setGoogleVolumeInfoDtos(volumeInfoDto);

    GoogleItemDto[] itemDto = new GoogleItemDto[1];
    itemDto[0] = item;

    GoogleBooksRatingDto ratingDto = new GoogleBooksRatingDto();
    ratingDto.setItems(itemDto);

    ResponseEntity<GoogleBooksRatingDto> response = new ResponseEntity<>(
            ratingDto,
            new HttpHeaders(),
            HttpStatus.OK
    );
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("body");
    
    when(restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, GoogleBooksRatingDto.class)).thenReturn(response);

    // When
    List<GoogleItemDto> ratings = bookRatingsClient.getRatings();
    // Then
}
```

I use those two methods only in my client component so I think there no point on create new component for those methods. I believe there is some way how to go around this.

Comment: If you are unit testing the given class, then you should not mock any method on it. What you should do is actually have tests that actually test those private methods as well (because they are used by the public method).

Comment: You don't stub `restTemplate.exchange` correctly. `HttpEntity.equals` takes both body and headers into account. You are missing the headers in test code. You have 2 options: 1. create correct headers in test. 2. relax requirements on httpEntity by using an ArgumentMatcher